# Why should the input_shape property of a Conv2D layer be specified only for the first Conv2D layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am new to AI/ML stuff. I'm learning TensorFlow. In some tutorial, I noticed that the `input_shape` argument of a `Conv2D` layer was specified only for the first. Code looked kinda like this:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu',
                           input_shape=(300,300,3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
```

In many examples, not only in the above, the instructor didn't include that argument in there. Is there any reason for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next layers derive the required shape from the output of the previous layer. That is, the `MaxPooling2D` layer derives its input shape based on the output of the `Conv2D` layer and so on. Note that in your sequential model, you don't even need to define an input_shape in the first layer. It is able to derive the `input_shape` if you feed it real data, which gives you a bit more flexibility since you don't have to hard-code the input shape:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
tf.random.set_seed(1)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu',),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

print(model(tf.random.normal((1, 300, 300, 3))))
```

```
tf.Tensor([[0.6059081]], shape=(1, 1), dtype=float32)
```

If data with an incorrect shape, for example (300, 3) instead of (300, 300, 3), is passed to your model, an error occurs because a `Conv2D` layer requires a 3D input excluding the batch dimension.
If your model does not have an `input_shape`, you will, however, not be able to call `model.summary()` to view your network. First you would have to build your model with an input shape:

```py
model.build(input_shape=(1, 300, 300, 3))
model.summary()
```